# Multiplicity of the roots of $-x^5+2x^2+3x+5$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consultation. What strategy can be used to prove that the roots of the polynomial $-x^3+2x^2+3x+5$ have no multiplicity? (over complex)

Comment: Calculate the gcd with the derivative.

Comment: Polynomials in title and body are different.

Comment: Please insert the problem also in the text, not only in the title. Please show the own effort to solve the problem. The simplest way to proceed goes through the computation of the discriminant, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant, or of related objects.

Comment: I personally like @KentaS 's method. If $f(x)$ has a repeated root so $f(x) = (x-a)^ng(x)$ then $f'(x) = n(x-a)^{n-1}g(x)+g'(x)(x-a)^n$, so $(x-a)$ divides both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Comment: thanks! jejeje.